# is it possible to show Loader image without setTimeout & ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just need to know if it is possible to load a loader without use of SetTimeout and ajax request?

For example:

```
showLoader() ;

Function_that_process();

hideLoader();
```

Comment: It(loader div) is an image which can be show and hide on whatever event you want to do this.

Comment: You just need to know when the "function that process" is ending, and only then hide the loader.

Answer (score 0):

Loader images are just standard images that are hidden on a callback event in jquery.

Without ajax you simple do what you stated.  In your showLoader() function you display the image you want, do any logic you want then on hideLoader() you hide the image.

The problem with this however is this is synchronous, this will lock your UI and is generally a bad idea, this is the reasoon people use AJAX since calls are made asynchronously.  This is not to say that doing such things is wrong, there are situations where your application needs to process something before it can continue.

Answer (score 0):

by using jQuery this way:

```
$(function(){
    showLoader();
    $(window).load(function(){
        hideLoader(); 
        Function_that_process();     
    });    


});
```